# Django Celery Rate Limit setting doesn't work as expected

Tags: celery, celery-task, rate-limiting

I use below command to create one worker:

```
celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=50 -Q celery,token_1 -n token_1
```

And in my task, I set the rate limit to `4000/m`.

However, when I start running the collection, I noticed the average task processed is just around `10-20/s` (with rate limit rule `4000/m` enabled).
Then, I removed the rate limit rule, now the task rates goes to around 60/s.

I am confused, since my rate limit is `4000/m`, which is relatively `65/s`. Why it finally goes just `10-20/s`????? (I have already set 50 threads for the worker....)

Comment: Anybody has some idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how the rate limits operate in celery.  ['According to the documentation on version 4.2](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.rate_limit):

> The rate limits can be specified in seconds, minutes or hours by appending *“/s”*`, *“/m”* or *“/h”* to the value. Tasks will be evenly distributed over the specified time frame.
>
> Example: *`“100/m”`* (hundred tasks a minute). This will enforce a minimum delay of 600ms between starting two tasks on the same worker instance.

In essence, celery was adding a forced delay between your tasks.  Since each task was already processing in about 16ms (1/60 of a second), adding another 16 ms forced delay between tasks reduced the rate at which they would process.

Comment: How does the 16ms forced delay calculate? (by the rate limit?)

Comment: Also, i set 4000/m, as the definition, it will evenly distribute 4000 tasks over one min, correct? But it doesn't make sence now.

Comment: forced delay = 1 minute / 4000 tasks = 60 seconds / 4000 tasks = 3 seconds / 200 tasks = .015 seconds = 15 milliseconds.  Add in a little fudge factor for clock, and you get 16 milliseconds.  note that what that second sentence in the quote means is that tasks will be evenly distributed *assuming each task completed instantaneously and in the same amount of time*.